# Probability that out of 6 districts in a city some city has more than 1 robbery.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A city with 6 districts has 6 robberies in a particular week. Assume the robberies are located randomly, with all possibilities for which robbery occurred where equally likely. What is the probability that some district had more than 1 robbery?

My solution is $$1-(\frac{1}{\binom{11}{6}})$$

Lets say A is the event that more than one robberies occur in some district.
This is not possible only if all districts have 1 robbery which would be $A^c$

I figured there are $\binom{11}{6}$ in which the 6 robberies can happen in 6 districts.
and exactly one way in which each district can have a robbery $A^c$.
So $P(A)=1-P(A^c)$.Is this right?

Comment: Not following.  The problem is not clear.  I read it as assuming that each robbery is equally likely to be in any of the districts, independently of the other robberies.  Is that what you meant?  If so, the probability that each district gets a robbery is $1\times \frac 56\times \frac 46\times \frac 36\times \frac 26\times \frac 16$.

Comment: Should say:  if you are trying to use Stars and Bars, then note that this is a very different probability distribution.  Using the assumption I made in my first comment, it is not true that all the possible patterns of robberies are equiprobable.

Comment: how is this different from stars and bars?

Comment: For the reason I said.  Not all the patterns are equally probable.  Suppose I flip a coin twice and count the Heads and Talis in an ordered pair $(H,T)$.  Stars and Bars gives me three patterns:  $(2,0), (1,1), (0,2)$.  But these are not equally probable.  $P(2,0)=P(0,2)=\frac 14$ while $P(1,1)=\frac 12$.

Comment: so you mean to say stars and bars is not applicable when all cases are not equally probable?

Comment: Once again:  on the assumption that each robbery occurs in a district uniformly at random and independently of the other robberies (which, I think, is the only sensible assumption here) then Stars and Bars has no bearing on your problem because the patterns it counts are not equally probable.

Comment: The outcomes counted in stars and bars are almost never equiprobable in practice.  If they happen to be, then it is a very special occurrence and is almost always explicitly stated in the problem itself.  Real-world applications of balls-in-bins style problems (*such as this, balls as robberies and bins as districts*) are almost always intended as each ball is temporarily (*or permanently*) treated as distinct and is individually assigned to a bin independently at random from the available positions.

Comment: As for another way to view the answer... looking at it via multiplication principle of probability as lulu had is fine (*and is how I find many beginning students prefer*).  If you are more combinatorially minded and prefer counting arguments, there are $6^6$ equally likely outcomes (*if we were to treat the robberies as distinct, as they should*) and $6!$ ways in which they occur in all different districts.  This gives an answer of $1-\Pr(A^c)=1-\frac{6!}{6^6}$, which you can see is equal to lulu's given in the first comment.